# Верстка: полоса прокрутки - смещение контента

Tags: вёрстка, css

Контент странички позиционируется по центру с помощью класса .all

```
.all{
    margin:auto;
    padding:0px;
    width:1000px;   
}
```

Когда появляется вертикальная полоса прокрутки, контент сдвигается на некоторое количество px влево.

Как избавиться от этого плохого "эффекта" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавь к `body` `overflow-y:scroll;` и полоса прокрутки будет всегда, а когда контент зона меньше в высоту чем высота окна, прокрутка будет не активна, но место занимать свое уже будет, и такого эффекта сдвига не произойдет.

P.S. Свойство это недействительно!

Comment: Я написал невалидно. Expert - исправил на недействительно. Что значит недействительно?(вопрос Expert'у). Оно работает, только css валидацию не пройдет - будет ошибка, такого своства нет в спецификации.

Comment: я, конечно, не Expert, но слова "невалидно" нет в русском языке. а слово valid - именно так и переводится)))

Comment: Слово валидность в русском языке есть точно. Невалидно - однокоренное краткое прилагательное, вроде верно все, хотя могу и ошибаться...

Comment: да, слово есть. оно имеет происхождение из английского термина. но образование наречий - это уже сленг. это мы с Вами понимаем, что означает термин "невалидный", но по факту это должно звучать по-другому: "документ не прошёл валидацию". вот есть слово "сатисфакция" (приблизительно удовлетворение), но, когда нужно употребить "неудовлетворительно" - мы же не говорим "несатисфично".

Comment: Да, вполне логично, убедил. Тем не менее в данном контексте недействительно не синоним невалидно, по крайней мере под валидно/невалидно понимается соответствие/несоответствие неким стандартам, а вот недействительно не совсем то. Автор поста может неверно понять слово "недействительно", подумав, что оно не работает или еще что-то в этом роде...

Comment: спорили, спорили, а то, что это свойство нужно применить к тегу html, чтобы везде нормально работало - забыли.

Answer (score 0):

Ну это логично, что при появлении будет смещаться влево, потому что под отображение страницы уже отводится меньше пикселов в ширину. Так как у Вас задано `margin-left` и `margin-right` в "автоматический режим", то и значение полей изменяется с изменением ширины страницы. Но чтобы контент оставался по середине области отображения, происходит эффект смещения. Боюсь, что этого не избежать...